# Include different file with defining preprocessor variable

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor

I saw very nice example for using different classes using `-D` compile switch.

However, in my use case, the thing is bit different and I can don't know how to do it.

For multiplexing API, I have 3 classes in 3 different files:

```
poll.h   -> class PollSelector   -> generic poll() works everywhere
epoll.h  -> class EPollSelector  -> Linux only epoll support
kqueue.h -> class KqueueSelector -> MacOS only kqueue
```

All 3 clases have same methods, so I use:

```
#include "selector/poll.h"
using MySelector = PollSelector;
```

I am thinking, if there a way to be able to do it with `-D` switch, but in same time, if I add additional multiplexing class, to be able to switch it only with `-D` flag, without edit the file that use it.

The way I imaging it is to have command like:

```
gcc -Dkqueue file.h
```

this automatically do

```
#include "selector/kqueue.h";
using MySelector = kqueue_selector; // I will do this typedef in kqueue.h so it will compile
```

Can this be done in clean way, without "diving" in C preprocessor?

Here are the original link to source
https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM4/tree/master/net/selector

Comment: Try to wrap your code inside a `namespace` (One_class, Two_class, ..., for instance, but choose a better name). Then `#define MY_SELECTOR = One_class`. And when you use the class remember to add the namespace: `MY_SELECTOR::My_class`. Then in your makefile choose `MY_SELECTOR` as you like. I believe this answer your question using your ideas (or maybe not), but I don't like this solution.

Comment: question is how to include the files?

Comment: E.g. `#include SELECTOR_HEADER` in the source, `-DSELECTOR_HEADER="selector/poll.h"` on the command line. More generally, the argument of `#include` directive is subject to the usual macro expansion. I'm not sure what you mean by "diving"; it's unclear what use of the preprocessor you do or do not consider permissible.

Comment: I do not understand the question. `Can this be done in clean way, without "diving" in C preprocessor?` _What_ exactly do you _want_ actually do to? `The way I imaging it is to have command like: gcc -Dkqueue` If you _want_ to have that command, and you _want_ to choose the Selector with a define, then it can be done. But you stated (I think) that you _want_ to use a macro and then that you don't want to use C preprocessor, so I do not understand. Plese explain what does "diving in C preprocessor" means, does it mean not using C preprocessor at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
generic poll() works everywhere
Linux only epoll support
MacOS only kqueue
```

I *guess* you intent to do:

```
#if __LINUX__
#include "selector/kqueue.h"
using MySelector = KqueueSelector;
#elif __OSX__
#include "selector/kqueue.h";
using MySelector = EPollSelector;
#else
#include "selector/poll.h";
using MySelector = PollSelector;
#endif
```